# What is the instance location and access specifier of the control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, access-modifiers

For example, create a wpf project and add the following code to the MainWindow.xaml file.

```
<Grid>
   <Button x:Name="buttonControl" Content="Button" Margin="332,145,0,0" Width="75"/>
   <local:UserControl1/>
</Grid>
```

1. Here, MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs (code behind) are one object, and instances of Button (wpf standard control) and UserControl1 (user control) are created as belonging to MainWindow object. Did I understand correctly?
2. And the control's default access modifier seems to be public, should I specify it like this?

```
<Grid>
   <Button x:Name="buttonControl" x:FieldModifier="Private" Content="Button" Margin="332,145,0,0" Width="75"/>
   <local:UserControl1 x:FieldModifier="Private" />
</Grid>
```

Is this the basic usage?

Comment: The default access modifier is `internal`. You can easily find that out by yourself by inspecting the generated code. And there is no need to change it.

Comment: Numerous other controls have been added to my UserControl1. And users using UserControl1 can directly access other controls used inside. Some of the controls included do not want to expose the logic to the outside, but is it customary to declare it internal?

Comment: Kind of the point of encapsulation is internal logic is not exposed. Or at least part of the aim. So yes. Not only is this default behaviour it's usual and bad practice to alter it. You could expose a dependency property, event or method from the usercontrol. What is usual in wpf is to work with the data in a viewmodel and bind from a property in that to a property in a usercontrol. That includes properties such as the text of a textbox or ischecked of a checkbox, command of a button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What to do in this case? My UserControl1 includes not only wpf's standard controls, but also user controls created by someone. There is a 'screen' user control showing some status, and this 'screen' user control only serves to show the status. Soon, it is a readonly control (Of course, in my UserControl1, access the 'screen' user control and modify the data.). This 'screen' user control can be added directly to xaml. So, should it be declared 'internal' even in this case? Should the part related to encapsulation be managed in the 'screen' user control itself?

Comment: The current state is that when my UserControl1 object is created, 'screen' user control data can be modified by accessing the instance of UserControl1.

Comment: The ideal approach would be not to have any `x:Name`directives at all, and only let the UI elements bind their properties to properties of a view model object.

Comment: Declaring `<local:UserControl1 x:FieldModifier="Private" />` is pointless anyway, because no field is generated - and hence no accessibility is altered - when there is no `x:Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to differentiate between class access modifiers and XAML element references access modifiers. A XAML defined object's visibility is defined by its [namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes). This means a control that is part of a `UserControl` is not directly visible or accessible outside the control.

If you give the control a name using the  `x:Name` directive, then and only then the compiler creates an `internal` field in the partial class, that references the named element (instance). By default this field can only be referenced by qualifying the partial class in an `internal` scope. If you want the field to be accessible in a `public` scope, you can use the `x:FieldModifier` attribute to adjust the field's visibility. That's what the `x:FieldModifier` attribute is for.

You only have to care about class modifiers and not UI element field references.
If the object itself is not defined `public`, you can't create instances of it or reference it e.g., for a type cast, outside the visibility.

But since you want to allow instantiation of `Screen` in XAML, it *must* contain a `public` default constructor and must have a `public` visibility. If you want to forbid subclassing you can `seal` the type:

```
public sealed class Screen
{
  public Screen()
  {}
}
```

There is no point in defining `Screen` `internal` if it is designed to be used `public`. This should be obvious.